# Zend Autoloader sowing error

Tags: zend-framework

My directory structure looks like:

```
   Application
   Config
   Control
   Form
   Layout
   Models
     |
     ----Db
         |
          ---Db_Db.php
   Views
   Bootstrap
```

I added this code in my bootstrap file:

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{   
 $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
'basePath'  => '/../models/',
'namespace' => 'Db',
));
$resourceLoader->addResourceType('Db', 'Db/', 'Db'); 
}
```

And In one of My controller I am using:

```
    require_once "Db_Db.php";
```

But its giving me an error:

> Warning: require_once(Db_Db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\htdocs\helloworld\application\controllers\AccountController.php on line 41
>   Call Stack

Can you please tell what is possibly going wrong?

Also my `Bootstrap` file only contains the above code rest all my stuff like Application environment n all are in `index.php` under public folder will that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you assume you have Db_Db namespace and class name should be Db_Db_Db. Second thing, use APPLICATION_PATH constant to make path right. Just do it as follows:

```
$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
    'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../models/',
    'namespace' => ''
));
```

Answer (score 0):

For loading files you should use Zend_Autoloader over require_once that will follow all autoloading configurations from zend framework.

refer this http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.load.html

what class name you have given in file Db_Db.php?